# Shopfiy - Liquid - Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, shopify, liquid

Can anyone figure out why only get one column even though I use the `col-md-6` class?

```
div class="container">
{% for member in section.blocks %}
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
    {% if member.settings.photo %}
    {{member.settings.photo | img_url: '300x' | img_tag }}   
    {%  endif %}
    <h3>{{ member.settings.name }}</h3>
    <span>{{ member.settings.title }}</span>
    <p>{{ member.settings.bio }}</p>
  </div>
   </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tiEo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Because your each row contains only one column. To fix this, you have to output 2 columns in each row. To do so, you can use the conditional operators like below

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row"> <!-- opening row, outside loop -->
{% for member in section.blocks %}
 {% assign remainder = forloop.index0 | modulo:2 %}
 <!-- condition to close previous row div and open new one  -->
 {% if forloop.index0 !=0 AND remainder == 0 %}
     </div><div class="row">
 {% endif %}
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
    {% if member.settings.photo %}
    {{member.settings.photo | img_url: '300x' | img_tag }}   
    {%  endif %}
    <h3>{{ member.settings.name }}</h3>
    <span>{{ member.settings.title }}</span>
    <p>{{ member.settings.bio }}</p>
  </div>
   </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div> <!-- closing row , opened outside loop-->
</div>
```

This code outputs two columns in each row. Check code comments for details.